# Не получается развернуть jar портлет на портале liferay 70

Tags: модули, liferay

Я добавляю портлет в папку `deploy`. Портлет появляется в папке `opt\lifrey\osgi\modules`, но на портале в панели приложений его нет. Что я делаю не так?

Версия Liferay 7.0+

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Приложите логи, иначе Вам никто помочь не сможет.

Answer (score 0):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Попробуй запаковывать портлет в war file. Библиотеки jar хранятся в контейнере osji.

Comment: Пожалуйста, переведите содержимое изображения. На этом сайте принято писать на русском языке. Спасибо.

Comment: - 3 файла для Liferay: Liferay WAR, Liferay зависимости (JAR) и Liferay зависимости для OSGI (JAR). Библиотеки пакуем в JAR, портлеты пакуем в WAR.